# Keep a UIButton selected for a fraction of time in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, uibutton

How can I keep a custom `UIButton` highlighted on selection, for about 5 seconds and then redirect to other view? In my code it is not showing any color when selected rather redirecting to other view.

This is my code :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 CGRect rect=CGRectMake(0+70*j,yy,79,40);
            UIButton *button=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
            [button setFrame:rect];
            [button setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
            button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
            NSString *settitle=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item.TimeStart];
            [button setTitle:settitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSString *tagValue=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%d",indexPath.section+1,i];
            button.tag=[tagValue intValue];
            [button setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];     
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
            [hlcell.contentView addSubview:button];
            [button release];
}

-(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
    Login *lgn=[[Login alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:lgn animated:NO];
    [lgn release];
}
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Have you tried [sender setSelected:YES]; ?

Comment: Yes I tried it .But of no use

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:yes` to the UIButton.

for example:

```
UIButton *click_btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    click_btn.frame=CGRectMake(238,10, 70, 70);
    [click_btn setTag:indexPath.row];
    [click_btn setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
    [click_btn addTarget:self action:@selector(sample) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:click_btn];
```

Comment: I didnot get.Acutally my UIbutton is created in UItableViewCell .How to do it then?

Comment: Actually the same thing I did .But did not get .I guess bcoz in IBAction I wrote to redirect it to other view it is not getting highlighted.So I want it to be highlighted for some little fraction of seconds and then redirect to other view .. may be with the timer but dono how?

Answer (score 0):

you just add inside that method  sleep(5);

for example:

This is user sample uibutton action method.

-(void)sample{

sleep(5);

sampleclass *classobject=[[sampleclass alloc]init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:classobject animated:YES];

}

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest using sleep() as this sleeps all threads and makes the app essentially dead for x seconds.

Highlight the button as per the instructions above and then use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(sample) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0f];


-(void)sample
{
     UIViewController *myNewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    enter code here
    [self presentModalViewController:myNewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: where should I write this? I have edited my code .Can u please have a look and say where should I modify ?

Comment: in the button press.
I am assuming you want to color the button then after 5 seconds perform a modal segue ?

If so place the modal segue in 

-(void)sample

Comment: Yes I want the button to be highlighted and then redirect to another view .because when it doesnot show any colour user cannot understand which button did he chose.So I want it to be highlighted > i tried ur code by placing it in  -(IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender but I m getting error :Program received signal 'SIGABRT' What elz should I modify ?

Comment: Where it says "sample" this refers to a method of your own that performs the transition to the next view, or whatever else you want it to do. So in this case:

-(void)sample
{
    [self presentModalViewController:theViewYouWantToSee animated:YES];
}